# Unable to send email via Django contact form

Tags: python, django, email

**Preface:** I can send email via the command line (using `send_mail()`) on my server. I can also send email from my `localhost` using the same SMTP settings. Additionally, I'm using *django-allauth* for user registration...and it's able to send out email verification emails just fine.

**Problem:** Mail is not sent by my contact form on my server, and no error is thrown. In fact, `send_mail()` is returning `1` (i.e. success), and the view is redirecting.

My **views.py** looks like the following:

```
class ContactFormView(FormView):

    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = 'contact.html'
    success_url = '/message-sent/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        subject = form.cleaned_data.get('subject')
        message = "{name} / {email} sent you the following message: ".format(
            name=form.cleaned_data.get('name'),
            email=form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        )
        message += "\n\n{0}".format(form.cleaned_data.get('message'))
        sender = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        recipients = ['mail1@example.com', 'mail2@example.com']
        honeypot = form.cleaned_data.get('phone_number')

        if not honeypot:
            send_mail(subject, message, sender, recipients)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

And my relevant **forms.py**:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    phone_number = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Phone Number (keep this empty, or the form won\'t submit)')  # honeypot
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Am I missing something super obvious?

**EDIT:** The credentials are definitely working (as mentioned, they're working from my local development environment, and I'm also able to send an email from the shell on my server using the same credentials). Enabling `fail_silently=False` doesn't result in an exception.

**EDIT_2:** I modified the view to look like the following:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    send_mail('Test Subject', 'Test Message', 'test@myemail.com', ['test@recipient.com'])
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

And received an email just fine. As you can see, no form data was passed to `send_mail()` in the above view.

Comment: are you using `dummy` in the smtp connection type by any chance?

Comment: Nope! Using the default `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'`

Comment: Have you been able to successfully send an email using your smtp credentials ? Also, you have an option `fail_silently` in send_mail - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail - do you get any exceptions there?

Comment: Yes, from my local environment. I'm using the same credentials to send email on my local environment. I'm also using the same credentials to `send_mail()` from the shell, on my server. The credentials are definitely fine. I'll re-enable `fail_silently` and get back to you on the second part.

Comment: Nope...no exceptions.

Comment: Your view redirect is going to happen regardless of error or not to the success url. Can you use `pdb` or `print to see the exact flow?` One more way I would debug this: Get the _exact_ params that are being sent into the `send_mail` and see if your shell sends email successfully. Oh.. and sorry for stating the obvious - make sure the recipients are a valid email inbox :D

Comment: Just tried something (see edit #2 above). I have a hunch about what it may be...but we'll see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaaand...the source of my 4 hours of debugging turned out to be my honeypot. More specifically, my browser's auto-complete filling in the honeypot.

I wasn't seeing problems in my local environment, because I don't have autocomplete enabled in my VM's browser. However, testing things on the staging/production server using the main browser of my host machine resulted in the honeypot (which is 5000px off screen) being filled.

This answer is here for anyone who happens upon a similar issue in the future.

**If you use a honeypot, and your form isn't sending email, turn off auto-complete!** Also be aware that keeping your honeypot visible (albeit, off screen) means that it can still be filled by normal users. It may be a good idea to actually hide it with JS.